# Custom Doxygen Translations

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen to build online "user documentation" for an application that supports simple Lua scripting of it's internal functions.

The application has the concepts of objects, properties and parameterized script commands, and can create a 'fake' C++ header file that describes them, which we then run through Doxygen.

All fine so far, but the Doxygen output contains phrases like "Public Member Functions" and I'd like to use a term more appropriate to the target audience, such as "Script Commands".

One way to do this would be a custom translation, but that means we're involved in modifying/rebuilding the doxygen source after every new Doxygen release. Another (rather ugly one) would be to run a SED script on the created HTML.

Is there any better way of customizing Doxygen output in this kind of way?

Answer (score 1):

There're no options for changing this in the XML file specifying the layout.  I think that would be the easiest place for it to be added.  I think the options you've enumerated are your best options.  Patching the source and compiling your own binary isn't as bad as you think in my opinion, because you only need to update and recompile when a feature you want to take advantage of becomes available.